# What is shudra-brahmin?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, shiva-purana, shudra

What is shudra-brahmin / shudra-kshatriya ?
Which is mentioned in [Shiva purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc384464.html)

Answer (score 3):

The verse you are talking about is the following:

> शूद्र ब्राह्मण इत्युक्तः स्वयमेव हि कर्षकः ।
>  असूयालुः परद्रो ही
> चंडालद्विज उच्यते ॥ ४ ॥
>
> śūdra brāhmaṇa ityuktaḥ svayameva hi karṣakaḥ |
>  asūyāluḥ paradro
> hī caṃḍāladvija ucyate || 4 ||
>
> *Shiva Purana Verse 1.13.4*

And the translation of the verse is found on [this page](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225558.html).

> 4. **A brahmin ploughing the field himself is a Śūdra brahmin**. One of envious and spiteful temperament is a degraded Dvija.

"svayameva hi karṣakaḥ" i.e. "who himself does the job of tilling the ground".

So, a "Shudra-Brahmin" is degraded Brahmin who himself ploughs the field.

There is the following verse in Parashara Smriti which apparently allows a Brahmin to do agriculture.

> 1. 2. Now, I shall explain, conformably to what Parasara formerly propounded, the law relating to the duties and observances prescribed
>       for a householder, in the age of Kali ; also the rules of conduct,
>       which, being common to all, are suited to the four castes and stages
>       of life, so far as they are able to follow.
>       **A Brahman who regularly performs the six ceremonies, may also betake himself to agriculture.**

But a commentary on this by Madhava says that this verse must not be taken to mean that a Brahmin himself is allowed to do the agricultural tasks himself. He should employ men to do such tasks.

> The six ceremonies have been enumerated in ch. I., S'loka 39. Madhava
> says that the causal form ' karayet,' in connection with the practice
> of agriculture allowed in the Kali to the priestly class, has a
> special meaning : — he says that a Brahmana must employ ploughmen of
> the lower caste in carrying on his agricultural operations **; he is
> not permitted himself to hold the plough**.]

A Vaishya's approved occupation is agriculture but it is not suited for Brahmins even when he is distressed. So, a Brahmin who is into agriculture is considered as fallen as mentioned in the Shiva Purana verse.

Manu Smriti says the following:

> 10.83. **But a Brahmana, or a Kshatriya, living by a Vaisya’s mode of subsistence, shall carefully avoid (the pursuit of) agriculture,**
> (which causes) injury to many beings and depends on others.
>
> 10.84. (Some) declare that agriculture is something excellent, (but) that means of subsistence is blamed by the virtuous; (for) the wooden
> (implement) with iron point injuries the earth and (the beings) living
> in the earth

A Brahmin (or even a Ksatriya), when in distress, can adopt the Vaishya's mode of living but even then he is advised not to indulge in agriculture.

Comment: That person Is shudra or brahmin

Comment: That person is a Brahmin (by birth) but by conduct he has degraded himself to the status of a Shudra. @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: In way  A shudra by birth, but he as brahmin qualities when he can became brahmin-shudra . and other question the brahmin-shudra should follow brahmin dharma or shudra dharma .

Comment: You are asking if similarly a Shudra by birth can become a Brahmin by good conduct? Well it might be possible but scriptures say it will happen only in his next life. BTW there is a Q on this site asking can a Shudra become Brahmin in this birth or not. You can check that @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: The Brahmin-Shudra follows the Brahmin Dharma but actually he is fallen so all those are not of much use @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: But isn't it true that there is no brahmin (by birth) but brahmin (by his qualities)?

Comment: No, there is "Brahmin by birth". @CloudJRK

Comment: So does that mean varna system is based on birth?

Comment: The varna system that can be practiced is only the birth based one. For e.g. in Mahabharata there is the character called Vidura whom every people would agree to consider as a Brahmin by gunas. But since he was a Shudra by birth he did not receive Upanayana (which only the men from the upper three castes are allowed to have). @CloudJRK

Comment: @CloudJRK a Brahmin is distinguished by qualities, but birth or blood highly correlates not cause one to be of one's Varna.

Comment: @Rickross I came across song (Agathiyar gnanam 30) of sage Agastya, he is saying the people who believe in materialistic world establish caste/varna I for their survival. So from his words one can infer that varna is created by people for their reasons and not a universal truth

Comment: @Rickross தானென்ற பெரியோர்கள் உலகத்து உள்ளே

தாயான பூரணத்தை அறிந்த பின்பு
தேனென்ற பானமதைப் பானம் செய்து

தெவிட்டாத மௌன சிவயோகம் செய்தார்
ஊனென்ற உடலை நம்பி இருந்த பேர்க்கே

ஒரு நான்கு வேதம் என்றும் நூல் ஆறென்றும்
நானென்றும் நீயென்றும் சாதி என்றும்

நாட்டினார் உலகத்தோர் பிழைக்கத் தானே

Comment: @Haridasa that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer this question. A Sudra will have to remain in his Varna likewise a Bramhana but their conduct here influences their respect in the society. Vidura though a Sudra was revered by Bramhins and Dharmavyadha a Butcher even taught Vedanta to Bramhins. People used to come in que to meet him!

- If one shows the **symptoms of being a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, vaiśya or śūdra**, as described above, even if he has appeared in a different class, he should be accepted according to
  those symptoms of classification.(SB 7.11.35)
- If satya, daana, karunya, lajja, daya and tapas are found in a Shudra
  then he does not remain a Shudra. Similarly if Satya etc qualities
  are not there in a brahmana then he will not remain a Brahmana.(MB
  Shanti 198)
- **If these characteristics be observable in a Sudra,
  and if they be not found in a Brahmana, then such a Sudra is no
  Sudra, and such a Brahmana is no Brahmana**.'(MB Shanti CLXXXIX)
- O serpent, **whoever has the characteristics of a Brahmana is said to
  be a Brahmana. One who doesn't have the characteristics of a Brahmana
  is a Sudra, even if he is "born" a Brahmana**. (MB Vana 180.26)
- Even a Śūdra who is richly endowed with the knowledge of the Vedas
  shall become a Brahmin and cultured. Even a Brahmin shall forfeit his
  Brahminhood and become a Śūdra if his conduct is base and if his diet
  and culture is base. **Brahma himself has said that even a Śūdra should
  be resorted to like a Brahmin, O gentle lady, if he is virtuous,
  purified by holy rites or if he has conquered his sense-organs**. **A
  Śūdra who clings to his duties, should be considered purer than the
  twice-born ones**. Neither the womb of birth, nor the consecratory
  rites, neither the Vedic knowledge nor the lineage can be the cause
  of Brahminhood. **Conduct is the real cause. All men are Brahmins if
  their conduct is pure**. Even a Śūdra who strictly adheres to good
  conduct attains Brahminhood(Brahma Purana 115.5.53-58)
- Yudhisthira said," In human society, O mighty and highly intelligent
  serpent, it is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of
  promiscuous intercourse among the four orders..Therefore, those that
  are wise have asserted that **character is the chief essential
  requisite. Whosoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous
  conduct, him have I, ere now, designated as a Brahmana**.(MB Aranya
  CLXXIX)
- O ruler of the Videhas, Brahmins learned in the Vedas, monarch,
  **regard a (virtuous) Sudra as equal to a Brahmin himself. I, however,
  O king, look upon such a Sudra as effulgent Vishnu of the universe,
  the foremost one in all the worlds**.” (MB Shanti 302,Shl 12-18)
- **Birth is not the cause, my friend; it is virtues which are the cause
  of welfare. Even a chandala observing the vow is considered as a
  Brahmana by the gods**(Uttara Gita)
- If a person happens to belong to a superior order but still if he
  happens to be divested of good behaviour, he should receive no
  respect or worship. **One may worship even a Sudra if he happens to be
  conversant with duties and be of good conduct**. A person proclaims
  himself by his own good and acts and by his good or bad disposition
  and birth. If one’s race of birth happens to be degraded for any
  reason, one soon raises it and makes it resplendent and famous by
  one’s acts.(MB Anu 13.2.49)
- **Those brahmanas who are devoid of the knowledge of Vedas and
  shaastras and are not performing Agnihotra are indeed equal to
  Shudras**. A dharmic king should not only collect taxes from them, he
  should make them serve him without paying wages.The following five
  types of brahmanas are considered to be chandalas (outcaste) among
  brahmanas. Those who call out the names of accuser, defendant and
  witnesses in court, who worship gods in temple by taking salary, who
  make a living by using nakshatra-vidya (astrology), who do the
  paurohitya (functions of a priest) of villages and who travel over
  ‘seas’(MB Shanti 76,Shl 1–6)